# How can I add npm (node.js package manager) to the PATH?

Tags: node.js, centos, cpanel, whm

I installed node.js like this:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
git clone --depth 1 http://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout origin/v0.4 # optional.  Note that master is unstable.
export JOBS=2 # optional, sets number of parallel commands.
mkdir ~/local
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node
make
make install
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/node/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

Then I executed this `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh` to install npm. After I logged out and logged back in, npm command wasn't recognized:

```
[/usr/local/bin/node]# npm install now
-bash: npm: command not found
```

What should I add to the PATH to have npm working?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
git clone https://github.com/npm/cli
cd npm/cli
sudo make install
```

That advice comes from of https://github.com/isaacs/npm#readme.

It is not as cute as curl|sh, but works.

Comment: apart from `rm -rf /` what does xmas do?

Comment: ASCII art, obviously! (Spoiler alert, there are xterm colors involved)

Comment: I'm getting this: fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
Clone of 'git://github.com/isaacs/abbrev-js.git' into submodule path 'node_modules/abbrev' failed
make: *** [submodules] Error 1

Comment: That's odd. Is your ethernet cable unplugged?

Comment: No, I'm doing these steps on a shared hosting server with +100 days of uptime!

Comment: The https://github.com/npm/npm.git repository is no longer used and has been archived.  https://github.com/npm/cli should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Great news : npm now comes with nodejs !

Comment: True, and yet still with `node` and `npm` both in `/usr/local/bin` I can run `node` but not `npm` from the terminal :(

Comment: And still not installed from `yum install nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner~, but I want be helpful.

I use centos7, and do you know yum (a tool could download and setup programs like mirosoft Windows)

First, I search keyword "node.js" at wiki.centos, I find this. https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/SCLo/CollectionsList?highlight=%28node.js%29.
There are two versions of nodejs could be used at the moment, I chose the higher one.
the URL is https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-nodejs4/
and the command lines are below:

```
# Install a package with repository for your system:
# On CentOS, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository:
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl-rh

# On RHEL, enable RHSCL repository for you system:
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms

# 2. Install the collection:
$ sudo yum install rh-nodejs4

# 3. Start using software collections:
$ scl enable rh-nodejs4 bash
```

Comment: I think it a very easy way to install nodejs than manual, wish you happy!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would like to note that this particular post is 6 years old at this point and already has another answer accepted, so it's unlikely your answer may be seen by a large number of people.